# How do I make an ActiveRecord scope that doesn't affect the query in Rails 3 using Arel (presumably)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel, scopes

Essentially I am looking for a no-op type of relation to apply to a chain of scopes.

Lets say I have a chain of scopes:

```
Post.approved.published.all
```

Now, for debugging purposes, I wish to make the `published` scope do nothing at all, so that the chain will only return `approved` posts, regardless of whether they are `published` or not.

What would I return in the following method:

```
def self.published
  # what to return?
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make `published` an alias for `all`, or use [`scoped`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes) to return a relation to which additional conditions can be chainged:

```
def self.published
  all
  #or
  scoped
end
```

I would use a scope, returning `all`...

```
scope :published, all
```

or, make it an alias for `scoped`:

```
scope :published, scoped
```

Comment: I was definitely looking for all, its so obvious now I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.

Comment: This is really old, but if you want the Relation rather than an array, use `scoped` to return an anonymous scope (Rails 3).

Comment: @kardeiz Yes, this is definitely the better method, I was unaware of it at the time I wrote this answer.

Comment: Now in Rails 4 you should no longer use `scoped`, but go back to `all`. :)  `all` now returns a relation.